# Referencing another field of subdocument in `$elemMatch`

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, pipeline, aggregation

I'm trying to perform an `$elemMatch` in a `$match` aggregation stage where I want to find if there is a document in an array (`commitments`) of subdocuments whose property `tracksThisWeek` is smaller than its `frequency` property, but I'm not sure how can I reference another field of the subdocument in question, I came up with:

```
{
    $match: {
        commitments: {
            $elemMatch: {
                tracksThisWeek: {
                    $lt: '$frequency',
                },
            },
        },
    },
},
```

I have a document in the collection that should be returned from this aggregation but isn't, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: i dont think you can the `$lt` query operator doesn't allow expressions, `{ field: { $lt: value } }` value cant be a field reference, if you stuck still maybe give example document and expected output, probably there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done, you can't reference any fields in the query language, What you can do is use `$expr` with aggregation operators, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$commitments",
                cond: {
                  $lt: [
                    "$$this.tracksThisWeek",
                    "$$this.frequency"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qFW8_A1WOA8)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! Now, I'm trying to make it so it only projects the documents that matched this condition instead of all of the documents in the array, and I came up with this: https://pastebin.com/DTuYHbyC . Not throwing any errors but also not working as expected, maybe you'd be able to help me out please? Thank you

Comment: You want to use the exact same filter in an additional step, like so
https://mongoplayground.net/p/GSXERtiwlYY

Comment: Perfect @Tom Slabbaert, thank you once again.